# Where have my whitespace gone, or why are there "empty text nodes" in my mvc generated html.

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-4

This is one is a strange one, so I'll start out with some MVC code (this is inside a td tag):

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => pile.NumCalsReturned)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => pile.NumCalsReturned, new SelectList(cals))
<br />
@if (pile.NTCal)
{
   @Html.LabelFor(m => pile.NumNTCalsReturned) 
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => pile.NumNTCalsReturned, new SelectList(cals))
}
```

I'm using the following style:

```
label {
    width: 140px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Now, I was pretty surprised when the output showed the second dropdown to be closer to it's label than the first.

[image: Visual of the text node indentation]

I tried expanding the width to 200px (plenty of whitespace between) but still the last label was further to the left. It was the same in both IE10 and Chrome. Inspecting the source code in IE10 I found the following weird "Empty text node"

[image: Empty text node IE10]

So, I found the following fix:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => pile.NumNTCalsReturned) 
<span></span> @* without this span, there is a whitespace missing *@
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => pile.NumNTCalsReturned, new SelectList(cals))
```

Now, I would really like some explanation as to what is going on here?

Comment: "Text - Empty Text Node" doesn't really do anything, and is nothing to worry about. The issue is with your CSS, almost certainly. Can you post your resulting HTML/CSS in a JSFiddle so we can see the code in action?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mGV2X/1/ Seems like it's related to MVC, for some reason MVC removes all whitespace between the label and dropdownlist within the if.